# matplotlib - break in the y axis for multiple bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a break in the y axis for the plot below. I've tried using the brokenaxis method (but I end up being unable to have headings on my bars and things didn't look great) and from the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html), but I can't seem to get it working. I either end up creating two figures with the exact plot I want but with no data and the other figure exactly the same as before. Can somebody help me out? Thanks

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from brokenaxes import brokenaxes

system_x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
x_indexes = np.arange(len(system_x))

width = 0.2

fig, (ax) = plt.subplots()

cof_1 = [15, 0.0798, 0.0696, 0.0540, 0.0616, 0.0601, 0.0590]
cof_2 = [0.3856, 0.1428, 0.1803, 0.1694, 0.1172, 0.1913, 0.1474]
cof_3 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2]
cof_4 = [0.0874, 0.0846, 0.0730, 0.1114, 0.0541, 0.0823, 0.0803]

r0 = ax.bar(x_indexes - 1.5*width, cof_1, label='1', color='crimson', width=width)
r1 = ax.bar(x_indexes - 0.5*width, cof_2, label='2', color='slategrey', width=width)
r2 = ax.bar(x_indexes + 0.5*width, cof_3,
            label='3', color='yellowgreen', width=width)
r3 = ax.bar(x_indexes + 1.5*width, cof_4, label='3', color='orange', width=width)


def autolabel(rects):

    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom', rotation='vertical',
                    fontweight='bold')


autolabel(r0)
autolabel(r1)
autolabel(r2)
autolabel(r3)

plt.xticks(ticks=x_indexes, labels=system_x)

plt.xlabel('Test')
plt.ylabel('Test1')
plt.title('Mean Test')
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_ylim([0, 10])

leg = plt.legend()

leg_lines = leg.get_lines()
leg_texts = leg.get_texts()

plt.setp(leg_lines, linewidth=4)

plt.grid(False)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are different scale, why don't you use log scale on `y`:

```
# modify auto label function
def autolabel(rects, vals):

    for rect,val in zip(rects,vals):
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(val),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3),
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom', rotation='vertical',
                    fontweight='bold')


autolabel(r0,cof_1)
autolabel(r1,cof_2)
autolabel(r2,cof_3)
autolabel(r3,cof_4)

# other codes
# ...

plt.xlabel('Test')
plt.ylabel('Test1')
plt.title('Mean Test')
plt.yscale('log')

# other codes
# ...
```

Output:

[image]

Also, consider plotting horizontal bars.

Comment: unfortunately, a log scale wouldn't work, I need the absolute value

Comment: You can use the original values to annotate. See updates.